# WHat does mAdvertiseFlags denotes in BELscan result

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

D/BluetoothLeScanner: onScanResult() - ScanResult{mDevice=78:85:99:F9:81:80, mScanRecord=ScanRecord [**mAdvertiseFlags**=4, mServiceUuids=[00007fd1-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb], ....

Is this denoting the "Table 3. Advertisement Data Type, Flags" as per the Section 2.4.1 for this General BLE document :

http://www.ti.com/lit/an/swra475a/swra475a.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Yes, mAdvertiseFlags gives you Byte 2 of table 3 of your linked document (Byte 0 and 1 are used only for identifying that this is flags information).

"4" means that Bit 2 is set, so BR/EDR is not supported.

Comment: It is the link you posted, in the table you have mentioned.

Comment: I mean from the Android Point (in the source code) , sorry for the confusion !

Comment: Sorry, I don't have any link for that. But it is strictly defined in the Bluetooth CoreSpec how advertising information has to be designed: Every element consists of a byte denoting the length of the element (without this length byte), the element type, and the element data. See CoreSpec v4.2, Vol. 3, Part C, chap. 11, and for more details on the advertising data format, see the core supplement CSS v6, Part A, chapter 1. I would be very surprised if Android would break the CoreSpec specifications.